# react threejs import json issue

Tags: json, reactjs, model

I have an project build on reactjs, using threejs 
https://github.com/toxicFork/react-three-renderer

When i import a json file exported from blender tool, i receive a response as my index.html file, does not json file i have imported. Could you help me resolve that!

My code:

```
let parsedModel = new ParsedModel()
    parsedModel.load('./shelf.json')
```

class parserModel:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader'
OBJLoader(THREE)

export default class ParsedModel {
 constructor (settings) {
    this._objectLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader()
  }
 loadJSON (url, settings) {
    if (typeof settings !== 'undefined') {
      this._parseSettings(settings)
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._objectLoader.load(
        url,
        // success callback
        (data) => {
          this.parse(data)
          resolve()
        },
        // progress callback
        () => {},
        // error callback
        (error) => {
          reject(error)
        }
      )
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you post it in your question? Also what do you mean by `i receive a response as my index.html file, does not json file i have imported.`?

Comment: Thanks @Stretch0, I have fixed. using https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin

 /*
     * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
     *
     * Copies project static assets.
     *
     * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
     */
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: 'src/assets',
      to: 'assets'
    }]),
and then copy file json three object into assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin

```
 /*
     * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
     *
     * Copies project static assets.
     *
     * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
     */
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: 'src/assets',
      to: 'assets'
    }]),
```

and then copy file json three object into assets folder